# Fixing Orphan user on Snapshot mirror

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, security, mirroring, logins

I am sort of confused about orphaned users in database snapshots created on the partner server participating in database mirroring.

Server A acts as principal for database X, with server B as its mirror, having database snapshot configured for that database X for reporting purposes.

We recently had a failover. After that I fixed the orphaned users in database X on server A.

However, when I view the same for the database Snapshot on server B, they are not listed.

If i manually try to fix orphans on X-snapshot on server B, it throws the error

> Failed to update database "X-snapshot" because the database is
>   read-only

The snapshot job runs every 30 mins.

Please clarify or suggest how to fix the orphaned users in the snapshot

Comment: Most likely your login security identification number (SID) does not match between server A and B.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can transfer the logins that are associated with orphaned users from server A to server B using the method explained in this KB article.

[How to transfer logins and passwords between instances of SQL Server](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/918992/how-to-transfer-logins-and-passwords-between-instances-of-sql-server)

Or you can use `Copy-DbaLogin` PowerShell command to do it.

[Copy-DbaLogin](https://dbatools.io/functions/copy-dbalogin/)